# Inserting a ModelValidator into a Model's Validators in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm currently trying to programmatically insert a ModelClientValidationStringLengthRule ModelValidator via a custom attribute, and wishing to avoid adding to the AdditionalValues dictionary in order to make use of existing functionality.

This is due to using a CMS, and wanting to control the length of the string via the CMS rather than within a model.

I assume I would do this in the OnMetadataCreated event in the custom attribute, however I cannot see how to add to the ModelValidator collection, only get them via GetValidators...

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than adding a custom attribute, you want to inject a validator based upon a condition.

You can use the class I detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7032340/how-to-add-validation-attribute-to-model-property-in-templateeditor-in-mvc3/7034007#7034007) to inject your validator based upon the conditions in your CMS.